# Optimized Permutation Code in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, permutation, executable-jar, performance

This is a code that I got from internet.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test<T> {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test<Integer> obj = new Test<Integer>();
        Collection<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                       input.add(i);

        }

        Collection<List<Integer>> output = obj.permute(input);
        int k = 0;
        Set<List<Integer>> pnr = null;
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.size(); i++)
        {
            pnr = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();
            for(List<Integer> integers : output){
            pnr.add(integers.subList(i, integers.size()));
            }
            k = input.size()- i;
            System.out.println("P("+input.size()+","+k+") :"+ 
            "Count ("+pnr.size()+") :- "+pnr);
        }
    }
    public Collection<List<T>> permute(Collection<T> input) {
        Collection<List<T>> output = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        if (input.isEmpty()) {
            output.add(new ArrayList<T>());
            return output;
        }
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(input);
        T head = list.get(0);
        List<T> rest = list.subList(1, list.size());
        for (List<T> permutations : permute(rest)) {
            List<List<T>> subLists = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= permutations.size(); i++) {
                List<T> subList = new ArrayList<T>();
                subList.addAll(permutations);
                subList.add(i, head);
                subLists.add(subList);
            }
            output.addAll(subLists);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

When I tried executing it, it took long time for the elements of count 7. But when I tried for 14, I got below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:329)
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:530)
    at Test.permute(Test.java:45)
    at Test.permute(Test.java:41)
    at Test.permute(Test.java:41)
    at Test.permute(Test.java:41)
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
Java Result: 1
```

My system configuration is 3rd Gen i5, 8GB RAM. While the program was running, CPU consumption was 98-100%.

**So my question is:**

- Is there any jar available for doing permutation efficiently?
- What can I do in this code to improve the performance?

**My requirement:**

- Need to permute a group (ie, more than 30) of integer values.

Downvoters please comment reason

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific with your problem statement? What is it you're permuting?

Comment: I have edited the question including my need.

Comment: When you say permute, is it to sort the elements?

Comment: @Padrus Sorting is not needed for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of generating all permutations first (as this has an exponentially growing amount of memory required)   I suggest you process each permutation as you generate it.  This means you only need to store one combination at a time.

You can generate all permutations of size 1 (or zero if that is allowed) and grow up to all permutations of all sizes.

Note: for your output you only need to calculate the number you would generate, you don't have to actually generate them.

Comment: So editing this code will be enough? Is there any jars available for doing permutation efficiently?

Comment: There could be, but given this is just an exercise I suspect you learn more by doing it yourself. It's just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the heap size a little: in [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror), or from the [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java).

However, if you want *all* permutations of 30 elements, you'll need `30! * 30 * 4` bytes of memory, which is 3e+22 TB...

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe there is a point being missed here.  You keep asking if there is a more 'efficient' or 'optimized' way to find all permutations of a set of numbers.

The number of possible permutations for 30 integers is a number with approximately 32 digits.  One gigabyte of ram is a number of bytes with 10 digits.  If you are talking about storing ALL the answers to this problem in memory at once, **it is conceivable that you could not do this even if you literally had all the RAM in the entire world.**

Peter's answer recognizes this in stating that while it is impossible to store the entire solution for >30 numbers, (never mind the time to calculate this), it IS possible to calculate a portion of the answer and generate more as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for what you are doing. However I can't see a way of reducing the method to reduce processing. So this is about as efficient as you can get it.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> calPermutations (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> n) {
    if (n.size() <= 0 || n == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> Result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {
        Integer num = n.get(i).get(0);
        for (int x = 1; x < n.get(i).size(); x++) {
            num *= n.get(i).get(x);
        }
        Result.add(num);
    }
    return Result;
}
```

However if the Java heap space error continues in Eclipse you can go to:

**Run->Run Configurations->Arguments**

Go to VM arguments and try:

```
-Xmx2048M
```

If this is too large for your RAM just decrease the numbers until you can find something that suits. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-application-heap-size-in-eclipse).