# What really is Java heap size in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I have read a lot of "increasing Java heap space" questions here in SO and I have yet to understand this question that's bugging me:

> If I increase the heap size in either the GUI via `> Run > Run Configurations > Arguments > type -Xmx2048m` or other size that you want ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601040/1685185)); or directly editing the `eclipse.ini` file ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601285/1685185)) with the necessary options, is the value I provided limited by my RAM or can it exceed that?

I only have access to a 2GB machine and I am performing operations on a 150,000-record dataset. I have tried both of the techniques I specified and it still failed.

Note: Specifically I am training the 150K dataset with the WEKA 3.7.10 API in my Eclipse Luna.

Comment: "_limited by my RAM or can it exceed that?_" How could you ever use more RAM than you have?

Comment: @Takendarkk: by swapping memory to disk.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you use the disk for java's heap?

Comment: @JB Nizet, how can I tell Eclipse/Java to use the memory in my HDD? I still have around 100GB free (I hope its possible :-))

Comment: The swap config is done at the OS-level, not at the JVM level. But that is not a suitable solution anyway. Your program would be dog slow. If you need more memory, then buy some, or optimize the memory consumption of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse itself is a Java program, that needs some memory to run. You can tweak the heap size used by Eclipse using the eclipse.ini file.

Eclipse also launches your program, in a separate JVM. You can tweak the memory settings used for your program by editing the run configuration used to launch this program.

If you tried setting that to a huge value, and your program still fails with OutOfMemoryErrors, then either you need even more memory, or you should optimize your code to make it use less memory.