# Egit - Clone repository from github hangs on receiving objects

Tags: git, github, egit, git-clone, gwtp

I am trying to clone the [GWTP repository on github](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP) using egit.

It receives objects up to 93% quite fast, then hangs for about 10 minutes and gives me a **Java Heap Space** error. This happens using **HTTPS and SSH** protocols:

[image: Always hangs on 93%]

I upped the git window cache in the settings but the same thing happens.

## Error Logs

Not sure if these will be of any help but here they are:

#### Exception Stack Trace

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.inflateAndReturn(PackParser.java:1492)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.resolveDeltas(PackParser.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.resolveDeltas(PackParser.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:752)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CloneOperation.run(CloneOperation.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.executeCloneOperation(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.access$2(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard$5.run(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

#### Session Data

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

I cloned another repository fine the other day so I'm really confused as to what might be causing this.

Comment: This might be a heap error b/c the repo is about ~374MB. There are a couple large commits in history, which might be causing it to hang, either through a time out, or more likely heap space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase heap memory and see if it does the trick.

Links for heap increase for Eclipse:

[Increasing heap space in Eclipse: (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

http://edwards.sdsu.edu/labsite/index.php/daniel/236-increasing-heap-size-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks. Setting -Xms512m and -Xmx1024m in my eclipse.ini did the trick!