# Eclipse LibGdx GPGS

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, google-play, libgdx

So I've been following the tutorial found at http://upandcrawling.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/libgdx-and-google-play-game-service-integration/

And I finally got everything in to my application, but I can't compile it in eclipse. I've looked up ways to change the amount of java space, but none really make sense or apply. This is because with libgdx you can't go into the window and preferences and change settings on a class. The classes used to start libgdx just don't appear

2 major questions:

1. When I try to compile the application it takes quote a few minutes which it never had done before. Is this Normal or should it still only take approximately a minute.
2. When I do compile it comes with a dex error, so I know it gets through the basic compiling, but why am I getting a java heap error? after all my app isn't like a 1 GB app, I'd reckon it's only about 10 MB, is there a way to increase data space in eclipse and if so how? (Preferably with screenshots, I'm very visual)

Comment: Yes, I have this exact same problem, things I've tried are increasing the space in the eclipse properties, but it still seems to have this problem, I'd appreciate if you figure out that you share how you accomplish it

Answer (score 1):

An output of your log files would be helpful in troubleshooting.

1. This is normal (for me anyway) when I compile it could take several minutes to build everything.
2. Check out these links:
   https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

   [Increasing heap space in Eclipse: (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: this might have been better suited to a comment, as it is asking for more information and doesn't really answer the question.  I understand you do not have the Rep for a comment at the time this answer was posted.

Comment: On the links. First Link: I've tried that, but to no avail as with that option eclipse tries to initialize Java Tools however never actually accomplishes it. It stays at 1% for over an hour. Second Link: I've tried that option, but first of all I have two versions of eclipse on my computer. First one is the regular eclipse and the second one is the Android Developer Package(I think that is what it is called.)