# Difference between Eclipse and Terminal execution

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal, benchmarking

When I execute a benchmark under Eclipse it takes a very long time and it crashes with a "OutofMemory Error: Java Heap Space".
If I do it through the Terminal there's no error, the program runs fine and very fast.

What can I change in Eclipse to have it work in the same way?

EDIT: More info. I'm running the DBMS HSQLDB with a performance test that cames with it.

This is the test:
java -server -Xmx1536M org.hsqldb.test.TestBench -tps 40 -driver org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver -url jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;hsqldb.tx=mvcc -user sa -init -clients 4 -tpc 8000

from http://www.hsqldb.org/web/hsqlPerformanceTests.html

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Comment: How do you launch it in the terminal?

Comment: I've added my launching options. Konstantinos' advice didn't work.