# How to define PremGen space in eclipse?Getting SpringContext initialization failed java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Here is the below Errors occurred while running java webapplication:-

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2014-11-02 23:26:35,690 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context         initialization failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1850)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1850)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:211)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:385)
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:222)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:505)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:362)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
```

Will anyone help me to solve this error? Is there any possibility to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has limited JVM PermGen space to manage all the applications running on it, thus when you say redeploy a application without managing the permgen properly it will consume more and more of it until it crashes, requiring full server restart.
T
his article has explanations on how to manage this problem.

http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/

Naturally more powerful servers/workstations will not see this error as quickly and have more room to move with (regarding configuration).

e.g. my weakling laptop gets the permgen error after 10 redployments, where as my main server can do unlimited due to proper management and resource availability.

Answer (score 0):

If it's running within Eclipse perhaps you need to set the Eclipse permgen:
  [Increasing heap space in Eclipse: (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror/8601040#8601040)