# Java heap space error in rabbithole project (Neo4j console)

Tags: java, eclipse, console, neo4j

I'm looking for a solution of the problem of **java heap space memory error**. It begans to make me tired, so I'd like to help me to find where can I set the value of the heap space java .. I'm working on the project of rabbithole and I dont know where I could find the specified java heap space memory. I'm also developing on eclipse and I already moved the value of max memory but nothing seems to be working.

Is there anyone who can help me as soon as possible ?

Thank you all

Comment: Some more details would be helpful.

Comment: you can follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Comment: I'd like to create at least 100k nodes but I can not do that with the limited java heap space. I tried to set the value of **maxmemorysize** in **eclipse.ini**to 4G but It still don't want to work. I'm using console.neo4j.com interface the same as the interface of the project rabbithole developed by Mr Michael Hunger (http://localhost:8080). Always displaying me on the terminal java heap space error

Comment: In my case, i'd like to run the whole project using Maven. I don't have a class to run with the argument added to "run configuration".

Comment: Why don't you use Neo4j itself? The Neo4j console is meant to be used for demo datasets of about 200 nodes and 100 rels not for huge ones.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer first..It would be great if I could use Neo4j itself, but I don't know how to make a relation between my rabbithole project and Neo4j engine, because, in the documentation of rabbithole which you developed, you mentionned that the project is run on the localhost:8080 which by default use Neo4j console. Is there any trick to bind my project to Neo4j engine which is more powerful ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use `mvn jetty:run` to start rabbithole. In this case you can use the environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS` to pass in additional JVM parameters. E.g. when you want to set heap space to 4GB (both max and initial size) use:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx4G -Xms4G" mvn jetty:run
```

Comment: where can I find the environment variable MAVEN_OPTS in eclipse please?

Comment: it displays me this time : 
2014-12-19 10:32:08,888 WARN  - ConsoleService             - ## cypher took: 164 ms.
org.neo4j.kernel.guard.GuardOperationsCountException: max ops (ops=1000001)

Comment: rabbithole has the `guards` enabled which impose a limit of 1M basic operations per statement (and a timeout as well). Adopt https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L19-L30 appropriately.

Comment: Thank you Mr Armbruster, it works very well, but the performances of my computer decreased considerably, is that normal nowing that I have 8G of memory available