# Whenever i try for gmail login integration in app every time i run it shows same error

Tags: java, android, gmail, gmail-api

Whenever i try for gmail login integration in app every time i run it shows same error "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space" and "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space" and asks "Do you want to exit workbench"  Please provide me some solution.Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your relevant `Copy/Pasted` code and logcat

Comment: have you tried increasing the heap for the ide. using eclipse or android studio,

Comment: Thank you Raghunandan for reply. But i have tried it but no any change.I am using eclipse

Comment: Why my question is voted down? I am getting problem and asking for same.

Comment: because your question doesn't clear out the problem you are facing and the scenario.

Comment: whatever i have problem i have explained it. The error i am getting i have  mentioned.

Comment: Check this link for your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space?lq=1

Comment: thanks amrit but i have refereed same link n tried but still same problem. My pc is linux 32 bit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with gmail integration. The problem is with eclipse

```
  "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space" and "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space"
```

This comes when the eclipse has memory related issues. Try restarting eclipse and/or your system. It should work.

Also you might want to make changes to your eclipse.ini file and increase the ram for eclipse so that this does not happen in the future.
You can do this by following the link:
[Increasing heap space in Eclipse: (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have done changes still same error.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: thanks atleast my error has gone

Comment: It worked for me when i was implementing only gmail login as different project. But, when i implemented same in another app onclick of gmail login it shows again same error.

Comment: Solved my error my setting  android:targetSdkVersion="22"