# Can logging a huge message (around 90 MB) cause OutOfMemory Error? (Max heap size : 2048M)

Tags: java

Actually, I receive a message through RabbitMQ which is large.
While consuming this message, we log it.

```
logger.info("payload: {}", payload);
```

I see the following exception in logs at the logger statement line.

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:272)
>       at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser$LiteralPatternConverter.format(PatternParser.java:419)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(PatternLayout.java:506)
>       at org.graylog2.GelfMessageFactory.makeMessage(GelfMessageFactory.java:37)
>       at org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender.append(GelfAppender.java:220)
>       at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
>       at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
>       at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
>       at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.info(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:324)

After getting rid of the logger statement, the message was processed successfully.

So, can I be sure that the logger was causing the `OutOfMemoryError`?
Or it is something else that is causing the `OutOfMemoryError`?

Heap size is : 2048M

Comment: Sure looks like it. What size is your heap space? Try assigning more heap space to the JVM using the -Xmx parameter .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing heap space in eclipse: (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: @JordiCastilla probably not. OP is just asking for assistance to verify whether is it the `logger` object the cause of OutOfMem exception.

Comment: Rise your heap space, or try : `logger.info("payload: "+ payload)`;

Comment: @SamuelToh IMO a 90mb log message shouldn't cause the error... but that  is just my opinion....

Comment: @JordiCastilla - yep 90mb is considered relatively small to a machine but strangely it is failing on the `Arrays.copyOf` api. Either OP's jvm really has got a real small heap size or maybe the `copyOf` api could have gotten into an infinite loop which cause heap to run out?

Comment: Outside the fact that it is causing such an error: Is logging every message content as "info" really useful? I'd consider that a performance bottleneck. I guess though, you cannot simply ditch the line, so you maybe want to perform a size-check and cut the message for log-output into smaller chunks or log only the first chunk.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem. There is no good reason to log an entire message. Why do you do this?

Comment: Indeed. Logging the entire payload is not a good approach here but note that this is potentially an incomplete code. Maybe the final version could be something like `if debugLevel == "everything"` then do so? @Raedwald, yes it can potentially be a performance bottleneck as this sort of operation can chew up disk I/O or CPU easily.

Comment: Max heap size is 2048M. Even I think that logging the entire payload is unnecessary hence got rid of it. But, I just wanted to confirm if logging could cause such error. I would like to thank everyone for responding to my question quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** So, can I be sure that the logger was causing the OutOfMemory error? Or it is something else that is causing the OutOfMemory Error?

**A:**
Based on the stack trace, yes.

From the trace you can evidently see that your log4j module (which is the `logger` object) was trying to perform a `copyOf()` operation but before the copy was done the program died with OutOfMemoryException.

As to how you would generally read the stack trace, this stackoverflow post can be a great help.

[How to read and understand the java stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688068/how-to-read-and-understand-the-java-stack-trace)

**Quote:**

> Generally the exact reason for the Exception is at the first line of
>   your Stack Trace, and for more information about the cause of that
>   exception, you need to gradually move down, and the root cause can
>   often be found somewhere near the bottom of the stack trace.

I generally read the first line of the stack trace to determine what is happening, for your cause would be the OOM error, then I move to the last line and read from bottom up to see which `object` or area of code that could have caused the fault.

Answer (score 0):

In your startup script of the application, memory parameters for initial heap size allocated to your application, and the maximum heap size for the same

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms) for details.
A startup command for the purpose can begin with something like

**java -Xmx12288m <(followed by other necessary parameters)>**

A sample command is given below for your reference

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx12288m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dlaser.home=$LASER_HOME -Djob=$job -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_NATIVE -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $job_runner insights-workflow.xml $job run.date=$runDate env.type=$env
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue for my application, but it was related to spring. In my code, somehow an autowired dependency class got marked as abstract and I started getting this issue on server startup.

After almost a day of research we were able to identify the issue and fix it.