# How can I increase JVM heap size in my application executable jar file? The project type is Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

How can I increase JVM heap size  in my application executable jar file?  The project type is Maven Project.

Comment: I don't think you can set heap size in a jar file.

Comment: The heap size can only be configured for the JVM which mean not possible within the executable jar only from outside via `java -X ...`...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this within the jar file. Instead, start your Jar-File `app.jar` with the following parameters:

```
java -jar -Xms30G -Xmx100G app.jar
```

- Xms: initial heap size (here 30 GB)
- Xmx: maximum heap size (here 100 GB)

Note that this is independent from your project type.

You can also set these parameters within your IDE:

- Eclipse: [Increasing heap space in Eclipse: (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)
- IntelliJ: [How to increase IDE memory limit in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac)
- (...)