# Error, Java heap space increase space in VM, using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, jvm, xssf

How about friends I get the following error in eclipse before it didn't come out, I read that it increased the VM but I already did it from the same IDE and from the configuration file and I still get the error. I really hope someone can help me.

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "TimerQueue"
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.ensureParent(Xobj.java:601)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.getNormal(Xobj.java:648)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.getNormal(Cur.java:2459)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.skip(Cur.java:1266)`enter code here`
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.moveNode(Cur.java:1835)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.createHelper(Cur.java:284)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.createElement(Cur.java:228)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.createElement(Cur.java:223)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.insertElement(Xobj.java:2098)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.add_element_user(Xobj.java:2179)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRowImpl.addNewC(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.createCell(XSSFRow.java:170)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.createCell(XSSFRow.java:145)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.createCell(XSSFRow.java:37)
    at Vista.Vista.btnexportActionPerformed(Vista.java:313)
    at Vista.Vista.access$0(Vista.java:283)
    at Vista.Vista$1.actionPerformed(Vista.java:107)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
```

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600972/increasing-heap-space-in-eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Comment: Note the eclipse.ini sets the memory for Eclipse, **not** programs you run from within Eclipse - you use the Run Configuration for that.

Comment: XSSF is known to be very memory consuming. You may try [the SXSSF alternative](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf).